# python3 text wrangling in an xml file

Tags: xml, python-3.x

Trying to parse XML files the way that you would parse a simple text file. In most of the tutorials that I've looked at they discuss elements etc. Is there a way just to sort through it and find keywords, etc. for instance if I want to find the UUID part or any line that includes "CLOUDATLAS_FTR-1_S_EN-" how exactly does that change when you are opening an XML file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?><DCinemaSecurityMessage xmlns="http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/430-3/2006/ETM" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:enc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
  <!-- Generated by Waimea 0.4.28l (wlib 0.9.53) -->
  <AuthenticatedPublic Id="ID_AuthenticatedPublic">
    <MessageId>urn:uuid:0bb31789-de90-4e17-859b-dc771ff97280</MessageId>
    <MessageType>http://www.smpte-ra.org/430-1/2006/KDM#kdm-key-type</MessageType>
    <AnnotationText>CLOUDATLAS_FTR-1_S_EN-EN_51_PRE_2K_20120830_ADC_OV ~ KDM for SM.Dolby256-DSP100-000004d8</AnnotationText>
    <IssueDate>2012-09-28T17:39:53+00:00</IssueDate>
    <Signer>
      <dsig:X509IssuerName>dnQualifier=G4c6KCUZh7AzcyJnMCXbf9GAfAA=,CN=.cc-wm-2336-000020,OU=.cc-ra-1a.s430-2.ca.cinecert.com,O=.ca.cinecert.com</dsig:X509IssuerName>
      <dsig:X509SerialNumber>61638</dsig:X509SerialNumber>
    </Signer>
    <RequiredExtensions>
      <KDMRequiredExtensions xmlns="http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/430-1/2006/KDM">
        <Recipient>
          <X509IssuerSerial>
            <dsig:X509IssuerName>dnQualifier=GCx2vAlHzkdwGCcO8/RwVow0PAo=,CN=.Cinea.CA.1,O=DC256.Cinea.Com,OU=CA1.DC256.Cinea.Com</dsig:X509IssuerName>
            <dsig:X509SerialNumber>1804</dsig:X509SerialNumber>
          </X509IssuerSerial>
          <X509SubjectName>dnQualifier=fz7SARXDJebOMN2832Kl0EfA4sg=,CN=SM.Dolby256-DSP100-000004d8,O=DC256.Cinea.Com,OU=DolbyShowPlayer</X509SubjectName>
        </Recipient>
        <CompositionPlaylistId>urn:uuid:194c16b9-f8ea-4d3c-9cc2-f9db651da636</CompositionPlaylistId>
        <ContentTitleText>CLOUDATLAS_FTR-1_S_EN-EN_51_PRE_2K_20120830_ADC_OV</ContentTitleText>
        <ContentKeysNotValidBefore>2012-09-28T07:00:00+00:00</ContentKeysNotValidBefore>
        <ContentKeysNotValidAfter>2012-11-16T05:59:00+00:00</ContentKeysNotValidAfter>
        <AuthorizedDeviceInfo>
          <DeviceListIdentifier>urn:uuid:12476d40-2f3f-4166-9013-fd6bfebf2b8a</DeviceListIdentifier>
          <DeviceList>
            <CertificateThumbprint>2jmj7l5rSw0yVb/vlWAYkK/YBwk=</CertificateThumbprint>
          </DeviceList>
        </AuthorizedDeviceInfo>
        <KeyIdList>
          <TypedKeyId>
            <KeyType>MDIK</KeyType>
            <KeyId>urn:uuid:5526f829-2e64-47db-acc4-7b3c092b4ebe</KeyId>
          </TypedKeyId>
          <TypedKeyId>
            <KeyType>MDAK</KeyType>
            <KeyId>urn:uuid:d87ed6e1-2b26-44c3-b338-fb82a65aaf5c</KeyId>
          </TypedKeyId>
          <TypedKeyId>
            <KeyType>MDIK</KeyType>
            <KeyId>urn:uuid:9d922467-7656-405e-87c1-c1e4957d3afe</KeyId>
          </TypedKeyId>
          <TypedKeyId>
            <KeyType>MDAK</KeyType>
            <KeyId>urn:uuid:8bf4778f-3582-4cfa-bb32-b35b699f0598</KeyId>
          </TypedKeyId>
          <TypedKeyId>
            <KeyType>MDIK</KeyType>
            <KeyId>urn:uuid:6316d846-26dc-4538-9994-8467ed76dea4</KeyId>
          </TypedKeyId>
          <TypedKeyId>
            <KeyType>MDAK</KeyType>
            <KeyId>urn:uuid:810b65bf-73aa-4728-9b1c-fb3a90df188d</KeyId>
          </TypedKeyId>
          <TypedKeyId>
            <KeyType>MDIK</KeyType>
            <KeyId>urn:uuid:2fe19612-b9a3-4819-ab1d-ddd9ac006319</KeyId>
          </TypedKeyId>
          <TypedKeyId>
            <KeyType>MDAK</KeyType>
            <KeyId>urn:uuid:1b703c28-d578-46c6-bca4-04c2741ad27e</KeyId>
          </TypedKeyId>
          <TypedKeyId>
            <KeyType>MDIK</KeyType>
            <KeyId>urn:uuid:1b6d67b6-e0eb-4715-97d6-11340aa3615a</KeyId>
          </TypedKeyId>
          <TypedKeyId>
            <KeyType>MDAK</KeyType>
            <KeyId>urn:uuid:73041ad7-47e3-459c-a554-2663e44916db</KeyId>
          </TypedKeyId>
          <TypedKeyId>
            <KeyType>MDIK</KeyType>
            <KeyId>urn:uuid:d57cfd00-6787-4566-8bf0-09374103953a</KeyId>
          </TypedKeyId>
          <TypedKeyId>
            <KeyType>MDAK</KeyType>
            <KeyId>urn:uuid:9caa3533-2395-4f53-8b4c-b8c801ee595c</KeyId>
          </TypedKeyId>
          <TypedKeyId>
            <KeyType>MDIK</KeyType>
            <KeyId>urn:uuid:db40255f-9ea2-47ce-a5ab-c825fd6a466d</KeyId>
          </TypedKeyId>
          <TypedKeyId>
            <KeyType>MDAK</KeyType>
            <KeyId>urn:uuid:06bc0f21-ae6b-43cd-8c7d-e8fbc0347d50</KeyId>
          </TypedKeyId>
          <TypedKeyId>
            <KeyType>MDIK</KeyType>
            <KeyId>urn:uuid:64f9da4f-91cf-4b2a-bb13-d95315351475</KeyId>
          </TypedKeyId>
          <TypedKeyId>
            <KeyType>MDAK</KeyType>
            <KeyId>urn:uuid:969330d5-fa3b-479a-b901-43d406d16400</KeyId>
          </TypedKeyId>
          <TypedKeyId>
            <KeyType>MDIK</KeyType>
            <KeyId>urn:uuid:c3aadc36-a395-4c34-a7ac-e1ec1c69df66</KeyId>
          </TypedKeyId>
          <TypedKeyId>
            <KeyType>MDAK</KeyType>
            <KeyId>urn:uuid:19746f06-1c00-4575-9ba0-7b13b6058a0d</KeyId>
          </TypedKeyId>
        </KeyIdList>
      </KDMRequiredExtensions>
    </RequiredExtensions>
    <NonCriticalExtensions/>
  </AuthenticatedPublic>
  <AuthenticatedPrivate Id="ID_AuthenticatedPrivate"><enc:EncryptedKey xmlns:enc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<enc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p">
<ds:DigestMethod xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
</enc:EncryptionMethod>
<enc:CipherData>
```

Comment: I was going to post how to parse it, but the document is missing several tags.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you'd want to use an XML parser, but for simple cases, you can use a regex to capture the data you're after.

For example:

```
import re
file = open(r'xmlfile.xml')
data = file.read()
file.close()
for uuid in re.findall('uuid:([a-z1-9-]+)<', data, re.DOTALL):
    print uuid
```

This should give you the basic approach so that you can extend the same idea to get the other data you mentioned fairly easily.

Comment: the file was too long to post, sorry for it being broken. Is there a better way than the regex? Something more pythonic, or is that likely to be the common approach?

Comment: I think the "pythonic way" would be to use a python xml parser, such as [xml.etree.ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), but you said that you wanted to parse it "like a simple text file" which implies using a regex.